# __threadfence implies the effect of __syncthreads?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, synchronization, reduction

I'm implementing parallel reduction in CUDA.

The kernel has a `__syncthreads` to wait for all threads to complete 2 reads from shared memory, which would then write back the sum to the shared memory.

Should I use a `__threadfence_block` to ensure that writes to shared memory are visible to all threads for the next iteration , or use `__syncthreads` as given in [NVIDIA's example](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__syncthreads()` implies a memory fence function as well.  This is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions):

> waits until all threads in the thread block have reached this point **and all global and shared memory accesses made by these threads prior to __syncthreads() are visible to all threads in the block.**

So in this case it would not be necessary to use `__threadfence_block()` in addition to `__syncthreads()`

You cannot substitute a threadfence function for the execution barrier in the usual general parallel reduction.  The execution barrier (`__syncthreads()`) is required in addition to the memory fencing function.  In the general case, it's generally necessary to wait for all threads to execute a given round of reduction before proceeding with the next round; `__threadfence_block()` by itself will not force warps to wait while other warps are executing a given round of reduction.

Therefore `__syncthreads()` is generally required, and assuming you have used it properly, the `__threadfence_block()` is generally not required.

`__syncthreads()` implies `__threadfence_block()`.

`__threadfence_block()` does not imply `__syncthreads()`